# Is there a quick way to find a built-in function by name search?

Tags: documentation

Is there a quick way to search all built-in Mathematica functions by name? Say I want to find all functions whose name contains "Graph", such as GraphPlot, NeighborhoodGraph, Subgraph, and so forth. When I enter "Graph" into Mathematica's documentation system, I get some, but not all of the functions whose names contain "Graph". I also get a lot of names which are not functions, as well as other material of varying relevance.

I just want to search for functions by name or partial name. Also, I don't want to see functions from optional packages -- only the basic ones that load when Mathematica starts up.

Comment: Try `?*Graph*` .

Comment: @b.gatessucks - Slow, as it searches half the internet. Also returns more than the built-in functions; the first entry is "cryptographic number theory".

Comment: @stevenvh On my system it is very fast and I only get the System` context.

Comment: @b.gatessucks - Are we talking about the help window? "graph" finds 714 results in < 1 second, "*graph*" finds 2192 results in 26(!) seconds. Searching half the internet may be incorrect, but that's the impression you get. The "cryptographic number theory" refers to the *Mathematica Guide*, but so do some entries in the "graph" search result.

Comment: @stevenvh No, you can type the command in a notebook. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @b.gatessucks - Yes, that's what I tried first, but that only returns "DegreeLexicographic, ParagraphSpacing, DegreeReverseLexicographic, Subgraph, Lexicographic, TextParagraph". Strange.
ParagraphIndent

Comment: @b.gatessucks I hadn't noticed the comments; please add an answer and I shall remove my answer, as you were earlier

Comment: @acl It's all good.

Comment: @stevenvh, note that it is case sensitive. I often find it better to miss out the first letter entirely `?*raph*` as this will pick up both cases.

Comment: Thank you, b.gatessucks. I knew about the question mark, but I didn't know it would accept a wildcard. I guess Mathematica has a lot of these hidden features.

Answer (score 10):

```
Names["*Graph*"]

(*
{"AcyclicGraphQ", 
.....
, "WheelGraph"}
*)
```

or

```
Information["*Graph*"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

In the Documentation Center, you can use the wildcard `*` as well, as in `*Graph*`. The difference between doing this in documentation or in the notebook interface (by typing `?*Graph*`) is:

- The notebook will give you a concise list of all matching names
- However, the above list will also contain names that are *not built-in* but have been defined by the user or in packages. The listings fortunately make it easy to tell which are the built-in definitions: they are under the `` `System` ``context.
- Sometimes you may be interested in finding functions that aren't in the system context but that are still part of *Mathematica*'s standard add-on packages. For example, the `Laplacian` is in in the vector analysis package which isn't loaded automatically but is part of *Mathematica*. This *won't* show up when you type `?Laplacian*` while the packages hasn't been loaded.
- In this case, doing the search `Laplacian*` in the Documentation Center may be the best way to look up that function.