# Pop-up documentation for "The new function of the day"

Tags: documentation, built-in-symbols

The Wolfram Language has more than 5000 built-in functions and constants.

```
functionslist = Flatten[
   Names[#] & /@ Flatten[
     {# <> "*", "$" <> # <> "*"} &
      /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"]
     ]
   ];
Length @ functionslist
```

> ```
> 5689
> ```

OK, 5689 have documentation in *Mathematica* 10.3, to be more precise. In order to keep up with that, I would like to pick randomly a function documentation to refresh.

```
SystemOpen["paclet:ref/" <> RandomChoice[functionslist]]
```

But I would like to refresh new functions more often than old ones.

```
SystemOpen["paclet:guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn103"]
```

> How can we implement a "New function of the day" function that focuses on functions new to the current version?

Bonus if it picks from all functions with decaying probability as a function of "age".

<sub>Code adapted from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69915/10397).</sub>

Comment: There are more symbols there than there is documentation for them. I'd scan `FileBaseNames` in References directory. To get dates you can prse the notebook to get "History" cell. `ImportNotebook` would be of great help but it is quite slow in context of 5k repetitions.

Comment: `WolframLanguageData["ArrayReshape", "DateIntroduced"]` may be useful.

Comment: Where would you put this command?  If you put it in your `init.m` file it would pop up a new function every time you restarted the kernel.  Is there some equivalent file that only loads when you open the frontend?

Comment: @JasonB  I would be happy to have a *procrastination palette* for that. :)

Comment: Do you mean a button? like press the button to get a new random function?  hmmmmm, I don't know how to make panels (are they called pallettes?  I haven't used the pallettes since I first found this software)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an alternative procedure using `EntityValue[]` and `Dataset[]`. The idea is to build a `Dataset[]` containing function names and the version numbers they were introduced in, and then use a query to pull all the names that are new in a particular version. One can then pick any of these names randomly. A way to bias newer functions over older ones is to use `RandomChoice[]` on the list of version numbers, with each version number being its own weight.

```
$versions = {1, 2, 2.2, 3, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 6, 7, 8, 9,
             10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3};

symtable = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"Name", "VersionIntroduced"}, #] & /@
           EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", {"Name", "VersionIntroduced"}]];

randomHelpPage := With[{version = RandomChoice[$versions -> $versions]},
         SystemOpen["paclet:ref/" <> RandomChoice[Normal[
                    symtable[Select[#VersionIntroduced == version &], "Name"]]]]]

Button["Random WL Function", randomHelpPage]
```

This should now function in a similar manner to Jason's solution.

Comment: When I run this code the button is created, but when I press it I get the errors `RandomChoice::lrwl: The items for choice EntityValue[][All,Name] should be a list or a rule weights -> choices. >>` and `String expected at position 2 in \
paclet:ref/<>RandomChoice[EntityValue[][All,Name]]. >>`. I'm on MMa 10.2 on OS X; removing the `10.3` from `$versions` didn't help either.

Comment: @freddie, did any errors occur while `symtable` was evaluated?

Comment: no but it is not much of a `Dataset` as it has only two elements and zero levels. It seems that `EntityValue` didn't do anything (I don't know what it is supposed to do, but running ` EntityValue['WolframLanguageSymbol', {'Name', 'VersionIntroduced'}]]` just outputs itself again).

Comment: Ah, that's why. I don't know why it's not working in 10.2; I'll do a confirmatory test later in that version.

Comment: @freddie, the code works in 10.2 on Xubuntu. Try it again in a fresh session.

Comment: @JM Ah, now it works. Yesterday running the code did not result in a connection to the Wolfram Knowledge Server, but now it did. Probably my home internet is too slow (5Mbps) and unreliable - I am at work now. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 10):

First we get a list of the functions, indexed by their introduction date.  The method suggested by Szabolics turned out to be very slow - although it has the advantage that it gives a date rather than just the year.

And as Kuba mentioned, the functions gathered by Rhermans's function do not all have help pages, so we just grab the file list from the help pages directory.

```
functiondatelist = Module[{dir, symbolslist, datelist, mmagrep},

   (*
   Here I'm scanning only what is in the 'ReferencePages/
   Symbols' directory, we could add other directories to scan 
   *)
   dir = 
    FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", 
      "System", "ReferencePages", "Symbols"};
   symbolslist = FileNames@FileNameJoin[{dir, "*"}];
   Print["Found " <> IntegerString@Length@symbolslist <> 
     " symbols with help pages"];
   (*
   Now we scan the notebooks for the phrase "Introduced in" and \
   thereby grep the year it was created.
   *)
   mmagrep[file_, patt_] := 
    With[{data = Import[file, "Lines"]}, 
     Pick[Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}], 
      StringFreeQ[data, patt], False]];
   Print["Scanning for introduction dates:"];

   Monitor[
    datelist = 
      Table[StringCases[
          mmagrep[symbolslist[[n]], "Introduced in"][[1, 2]], 
          DigitCharacter ..][[1]] // ToExpression, {n, 
        Length@symbolslist}];
    , n];

   (*Now bin up the list of functions by their year *)

   Reverse@SortBy[
     GatherBy[
      Transpose[{FileBaseName /@ symbolslist, 
        datelist}], #[[2]] &], #[[1, 2]] &]

   ];
```

The symbol-introduction years aren't evenly distributed,

```
DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@functiondatelist[[All, All, 2]]]

(*  {2015, 2014, 2012, 2010, 2008, 2007, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2000, 
      1999, 1996, 1993, 1991, 1988} *)
```

Choose some directory in your `$Path` where you like to keep packages, and create a folder titled `RandomHelp` to write this data to. I don't mind having a cluttered home directory so I just use

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{directoryinyourpath,"RandomHelp", "mma_symbollist.m"}], 
  functiondatelist];
```

Copy this text either into a text file named `init.m` inside the `RandomHelp` directory,

```
{symbollist, symbolintyears} = 
  Module[{temp}, 
   temp = Import[FileNameJoin[{"RandomHelp", "mma_symbollist.m"}]];
   {temp[[All, All, 1]], 
    DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@temp[[All, All, 2]]]}];

randomintroductionyear := Module[{test, gamma},
   gamma = 0.15;
   test = Length@symbolintyears + 1;
   While[test > Length@symbolintyears,
    test = Ceiling@RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[gamma]];
    ];
   test
   ];

randomnewhelppage :=
  Module[{year, symbol},
   year = randomintroductionyear;
   SystemOpen[
    "paclet:ref/" <> 
     symbollist[[year, RandomInteger[{1, Length@symbollist[[year]]}]]]]

   ];

Button["Procrastination Button", randomnewhelppage]
```

If you want to increase the bias towards the new, simply make the gamma value larger.  Here I have gamma set to 0.15 and 0.5, respectively

[image]

Save the `init.m` file, and now all you have to do is type

```
<< "RandomHelp`"
```

and you get a nice button

[image]

Comment: Nicely done. :) A note: it's safest to get the list of *documented* symbols from `EntityValue[#, "Name"] & /@ WolframLanguageData[]` instead of ``Names["System`*"]``; to use my favorite example, `SequenceLimit[]` is an undocumented system function, and it is indeed present in the latter list, but not the former.

Comment: @J.M. , what would the advantage that be over just getting the list of *.nb files in the `ReferencePages/Symbols/` directory?  Running `EntityValue[#, "Name"] & /@ WolframLanguageData[]` ran for over ten minutes and I got impatient and cancelled it.

Comment: Admittedly, it is slower than reading files (another current annoyance of `Entity[]` objects). It's short, which is apparently its only appeal. :(

Comment: @J.M. `WolframLanguageData[WolframLanguageData[], {"Name", "VersionIntroduced", "VersionLastModified", "URL"}]` is _much_ faster.

Comment: @WReach, so it is! Thanks!

Comment: @J.M. and @WReach, it's interesting to note that there are many undocumented symbols when you make the `WolframLanguageData` call.   For example, you get `InverseWishartMatrixDistribution` or `TravelDirectionsData`, and 73 other symbols that have no documentation page.

Comment: Strike that, they have documentation, but they are so new that I don't have them in my system since I have version 10.2.  So if I had version 10.3, they would be in my `ReferencePages/Symbols/` directory I assume.

Comment: It would be a great function to add to `https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository`